# Databind to DataTemplate.IsSelected to View Model

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I databind to the `DataTemplate`'s `IsSelected` property to my view model?

Comment: `DataTemplate` doesn't have `IsSelected` property. Please give more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose your `DataTemplate` is within an `ItemsControl` or a control that derives from it, like `ListBox`, `DataGrid` etc. In that case you bind `IsSelected` in the `ItemContainerStyle`

Example for `ListBox`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- ... -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: `Selected` is on each viewmodel in the collection that is my binding to the list box.

Comment: Then this should work find, did you try it? Each `DataTemplate` is in a `ListBoxItem` container and it is the container that has the `IsSelected` property. Both the `ListBoxItem` and the `DataTemplate` has the same `DataContext`